# How to remove last comma from print(string, end=“, ”)

Tags: python, python-3.x

my output from a forloop is

```
string = ""
for x in something:
   #some operation
   string =  x += string 

print(string)

5
66
777
```

I use the below code to have them on the same line

```
print(string, end=", ")
```

and then I get

```
5, 66, 777,
```

I want the final result to be

```
 5, 66, 777
```

How do I change the code `print(string, end=", ")` so that there is no `,` at the end

The above string is user input generated it can me just `1` or `2,3, 45, 98798, 45` etc

**So far I have tried**

```
print(string[:-1], end=", ")                   #result = , 6, 77, 
print((string, end=", ")[:-1])                 #SyntaxError: invalid syntax  
print((string, end=", ").replace(", $", ""))   #SyntaxError: invalid syntax  
print(", ".join([str(x) for x in string]))     # way off result 5
                                                                6, 6
                                                                    7, 7, 7
    print(string, end=", "[:-1])                  #result 5,66,777,(I thought this will work but no change to result)
   print(*string, sep=', ')                          #result 5
                                                             6, 6
                                                             7, 7, 7
```

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
user input
twenty five, four, nine
```

gets

```
25, 4, 9, #(that stupid comma in the end)
```

Comment: is `string` in your loop code at the top an empty string or does it contain the input you want to print?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could build a list of strings in your for loop and print afterword using `join`:

```
strings = []

for ...:
   # some work to generate string
   strings.append(sting)

print(', '.join(strings))
```

*alternatively*, if your `something` has a well-defined length (i.e you can `len(something)`), you can select the string terminator differently in the end case:

```
for i, x in enumerate(something):
   #some operation to generate string

   if i < len(something) - 1:
      print(string, end=', ')
   else:
      print(string)
```

UPDATE based on real example code:

Taking this piece of your code:

```
value = input("")
string = ""
for unit_value in value.split(", "):
    if unit_value.split(' ', 1)[0] == "negative":
        neg_value = unit_value.split(' ', 1)[1]
        string = "-" + str(challenge1(neg_value.lower()))
    else:
        string = str(challenge1(unit_value.lower()))

    print(string, end=", ")
```

and following the first suggestion above, I get:

```
value = input("")
string = ""
strings = []
for unit_value in value.split(", "):
    if unit_value.split(' ', 1)[0] == "negative":
        neg_value = unit_value.split(' ', 1)[1]
        string = "-" + str(challenge1(neg_value.lower()))
    else:
        string = str(challenge1(unit_value.lower()))

    strings.append(string)

print(', '.join(strings))
```

Comment: what exactly do I add in `something`

Comment: @SamirTendulkar: `something` is from the code you posted.  Happy to update this if you give a more detailed example of what you're working with.

Comment: I have added what I am working with. did not add it as it can be intimidating

Comment: @SamirTendulkar, Yep, you need to trim it to a **minimal** [mcve]. I advise you roll back while you work that out.

Comment: sorry I have made it simple

Comment: Please do read @jpp's link - minimal + *complete* is important.

Comment: Enumerate stuff is awesome.

Answer (score 5):

If you can first construct a list of strings, you can then use sequence unpacking within `print` and use `sep` instead of `end`:

```
strings = ['5', '66', '777']

print(*strings, sep=', ')

5, 66, 777
```

Comment: @SamirTendulkar, Unfortunately, I can't see your input. Can you update your example so it actually runs? For example, `string = ""` doesn't help.

Comment: The reason I used `print(string, end=", ")` is they stay on the same line with `print(*strings, sep=', ')` they print below each other

Answer (score 0):

In case your for loop is doing also something else than printing, then you can maintain your current structure with this approach.

```
 strings = ['5', '66', '777']

 for i in range(len(strings)-1):
      # some operation

      print(strings[i], end=', ')

 # some operation (last time)
 print(strings[-1])
```

> > 5, 66, 777

Comment: `print(strings[i], end=', ')` comes in with `5, 66, 777,`  if I run the print 2nd time `print(strings[-1]) `. It gets messed up . The result is `5`, next line `66`,6  next line `777`, 7

Answer (score 0):

see I have solved this to print 1 to 5
Previously:

```
i = 1
while i<=5:
    print(i, end=",")
    i=i+1
```

Output:==> 1,2,3,4,5,

Now

```
lst=[]
i=1
while i<=5:
    lst.append(str(i))
    i=i+1  
print(', '.join(lst))
```

Output:==> 1,2,3,4,5

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use a `if-condition` inside a `for-loop` like below

```
x=['1','2','3','4','5']           #Driver List
for i in range(0,len(x),1):       #This loop iterates through the driver list
    if( i==len(x)-1 ):            #This checks whether i reached the last positon in iteration
        print(i)                  #If i is in the last position, just print the value of i
    else:
        print(i,end=" , ")        #If i is not in the last position, print the value of i followed by a comma
```

The output for this code is:

```
0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4               #Notice that no comma is printed in the last position
```

Answer (score 0):

If text formatting is a concern, the simplest approach is to remove the last comma as shown in this example:

```
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"] 

for i in letters: 
    print(f"{i}".upper(), end=", ") # some text formatting applied
    
print("\b\b ")  # This removes the last comma.
```

Otherwise,

```
print (*letters, sep=", ")
```

works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(10):
    if(i==9):
        print(i)
    else:
        print(str(i),end=",")
```

> **output** : 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Answer (score 0):

x = "Environment"

j = []

for i in x:

```
j.append(i)
```

print(*j, sep = ", ")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

```py
list_name = [5, 10, 15, 20]
new_list = []
[new_list.append(f'({i}*{i+5})') for i in list_name] 
print(*new_list,sep="+") 

Output: (5*10)+(10*15)+(15*20)+(20*25)
```

Comment: Building an empty list, then doing list comprehension to mutate it, shows that you missed its point of list comprehension. In case you did not yet learned it since you answered, you should directly write `new_list = [f'({i}*{i+5})' for i in list_1]` ;-)

Answer (score -2):

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i, end="+")
    
print("10")
```

Output:

> 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10

in the end no + sign.