# Extra comma in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am new to python and learning loops now.
I want to make print numbers from 1 to n using loop in one line, for example if n=5 I want to see the output
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
So I make it like this:

```py
def function_name(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(i, end = ", ")
```

But I see 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 **,**  with extra comma.
How do I solve this?

Comment: if i == n:  print(i);else: print(i, end = ", ")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python how to remove last comma from print(string, end=“, ”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230513/python-how-to-remove-last-comma-from-printstring-end)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple ways to do this. You can join a list of strings together using `join()` and then print them:

```py
n=5
    
print(', '.join([str(i) for i in range(1, n+1)]))
```

Or you can print all the items from a list in a single `print()` statement using `sep=", "`

```py
print(*[i for i in range(1, n+1)], sep=", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is just to add up `print("\b\b ")` after exiting the loop as shown below:

```
n=5

for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(i, end = ", ")

print("\b\b ")
```

The above 3 lines output

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```