# How do I not end the output with the last comma?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**The problem says: Write a Python program which takes a number and prints the digits from the unit place, then the tenth, then hundredth, etc.**

In this program I've set end=", " to end each print with a comma

```
num=int(input("Enter a number: "))

while num!=0:
    div1=num%10
    print(div1,end=", ")
    num=num//10
```

Now, for example:

```
Input: 123456
Output: 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,
```

This is printed as I wrote the code. But I don't want to keep any comma(, ) at the very end, just like here there's a comma after 1. What should I do?

Comment: There are some good Posts here. But you could try this too - eg. num = '123456' result = ','.join(num[::-1])  #  '6,54,3,2,1'

Comment: @DanielHao Any reason you didn't add an answer?

Comment: @Cfomodz - please check the post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python how to remove last comma from print(string, end=“, ”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230513/python-how-to-remove-last-comma-from-printstring-end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the input number to a variable as you have, create an empty list of numbers `lon` to add each result (ones, tens, etc.) to. `while` the `num` that has been entered is not equal to 0, we will modulo by 10 (getting the remainder of the `num` divided by 10, or in other words, the number in the ones place, including if it is 0). We can then do integer division by 10, or look at how many times 10 'goes into' the number ignoring the remainder (the one's place which we have already 'taken out' into our `lon` and set this result equal to `num` and continue this operation (essentially stripping off each 'place' until there are no more places, at which point the number will be 0, and the loop will exit. The list of numbers will then be printed, starting at the ones place and continuing up to the tens, hundreds, thousands, etc.

```
num=int(input("Enter a number: "))
lon=[]
while num!=0:
    div1=num%10
    lon.append(div1)
    num=num//10
', '.join(str(lon))
print(lon)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num=int(input("Enter a number: "))
output = ""
while num!=0:
    div1=num%10
    output+=str(div1)+","
    num=num//10
print(output[:-1])   #STRING SLICING
```

Comment: String concatenation in a loop is very inefficient. It is better to create a list and then use `', '.join(li)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty string to prepend it before the value that's printed and set it to comma afterwards:

```
num=int(input("Enter a number: "))
output=""
comma=""

while num!=0:
    div1=num%10
    output+=comma+div1
    comma=","
    num=num//10
print output
```