# How do I loop through a list and print each element separated by commas without the last comma?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I'm trying to loop through the elements of a list, print them out, separate them by a comma but leave the trailing comma; all in a single loop. I'm aware of the join() method but I wanted to ask if there was a way to complete that within the loop?

This is the code I'm currently working with:

```
grades = [['A1', 12], ['A2', 18], ['A3', 20], ['A4', 19]]

for i in range(len(grades)):
    print(grades[i][0], end = ', ')
```

It keeps returning this:

```
A1, A2, A3, A4,
```

How do I stop that last comma from appearing?

Comment: Check `if i == len(grades) - 1` and if true, don’t print `,`. Or run the loop until `len(grades) - 1`, and print the last element after the loop.

Comment: `print(*[item[0] for item in grades], sep=", ")`. Use list comprehension to to create and expand the list inside a print statement, then just use the comma as a `sep` instead of end

Answer (score 1):

You can use `print` with `sep` parameter, or `join`:

```py
grades = [['A1', 12], ['A2', 18], ['A3', 20], ['A4', 19]]

print(*(x[0] for x in grades), sep=', ') # A1, A2, A3, A4

print(', '.join(x[0] for x in grades)) # A1, A2, A3, A4
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```
grades = [['A1', 12], ['A2', 18], ['A3', 20], ['A4', 19]]

for i in range(len(grades)):
    print(grades[i][0], end = ', ' if i != len(grades) - 1 else '')
```

I achieved this using the [ternary](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ternary-operator-in-python/) operator in Python. "i == len(grades) - 1" is True when i is the last index in the list.

I would also suggest checking out [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230513/how-to-remove-last-comma-from-printstring-end).